# No beans of session factory type found, config without xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im trying to implement this:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return txManager;
}
```

That is in my `DemoAppConfig` class.

But Im getting this error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalSessionFactoryBean'` and `Cannot resolve symbol 'HibernateTransactionManager'` and this for session factory: `Could not autowire. No beans of 'SessionFactory' type found.`

Also in my `EmployeeDAO` class im getting this same error:  `@Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;` for this:

```
   @Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Im creating this small app without any xml. m I missing something? Do I need to add some libraray manually for this?

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalSessionFactoryBean'` isn't that a compilation error?

Comment: This is not a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to create one, in order to get proper help.